# Did the authors of Jonah know Assyria would conquer Israel?

Tags: prophecy, jonah, assyria

Did the writers of Jonah employ dramatic irony by making Jonah aware that by successfully convincing the people of Nineveh, the capital of Assyria, to repent, he would set in place events that would see the conquering and enslavement of his own people.

2 Kings 15:29

> In the days of Pekah king of Israel came Tiglathpileser king of Assyria, . . . Gilead, and Galilee, all the land of Naphtali, and carried them captive to Assyria.

2 Kings 17:5

> Then the king of Assyria came up throughout all the land, and went up to Samaria, and besieged it three years.

This provides a very good motivation, Jonah 4:1,

> But it displeased Jonah exceedingly, and he was very angry.

It has been my assumption that the authors of Jonah knew this, and assume readers knew this. However, if this was written before the destruction caused by Assyria, then my understanding is flawed. Is there any way that the text of Jonah was written or modified after the destruction of Israel?

Comment: @Stevecanhelp I don't necessarily care who, just concentrate on when; _viz_ whether it is possible for them to have known of the destruction of Israel. I suppose that an equivalent question is, is the last probable date of writing or update after the fall of Israel? I've updated my question a little; thanks.

Comment: It's a good question. Hopefully you'll get a good range of answers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonah lived in the heyday of the Northern Kingdom, when Jeroboam II was king.

2 Kings 14:23-27 read

> 23 In the fifteenth year of Amaziah son of Joash king of Judah, Jeroboam son of Jehoash king of Israel became king in Samaria, and he reigned forty-one years.
>
> 24 He did evil in the eyes of the Lord and did not turn away from any of the sins of Jeroboam son of Nebat, which he had caused Israel to commit.
>
> 25 He was the one who restored the boundaries of Israel from Lebo Hamath to the Dead Sea, in accordance with the word of the Lord, the God of Israel, spoken through his servant **Jonah son of Amittai, the prophet from Gath Hepher**.
>
> 26 The Lord had seen how bitterly everyone in Israel, whether slave or free, was suffering; there was no one to help them.
>
> 27 **And since the Lord had not said he would blot out the name of Israel from under heaven, he saved them by the hand of Jeroboam son of Jehoash.**

Verse 25 mentioned Jonah son of Amittai, generally is taken as the same prophet of the Book of Jonah. Though Jeroboam II was wicked in the eyes of the Lord (vv24), the Lord gave mercy to the people of Israel (vv26), and delivered their suffering by the hand of Jeroboam II (vv27).

Did Jonah know Assyria would conquer Israel? Probably not. Otherwise, Jonah should prophesized the repentant, instead of restoration (vv25)

So why would Jonah reacted negatively against the message of the Lord? History of Assyria indicate that they were fearsome warriors, cruel and ruthless. In Johah perception, the Assyrian were the most wicked people than his Israel fellows.

Comment: I agree, Jonah had good reason to avoid the Assyrians, whether or not he knew of their fate. But is it possible that the authors of Jonah knew that fate as a matter of history?

Comment: @Neil - there is a reason why we don't know most of the authors of the scripture, as the scripture is a sacred book of the Lord, instead of man. Revelation 22:18 is a warning; "I warn everyone who hears the words of the prophecy of this scroll: If anyone adds anything to them, God will add to that person the plagues described in this scroll". For sure I believe the author, in the Spirit of the Lord, could only honestly have written what was needed, no matter he knew it or not.

Comment: I suppose my question could be phased as, could Jonah (through prophecy) or the author (through hindsight) know that the Assyrians would/have destroyed Israel. In all the commentary I've read, it seems to make Jonah kind of shallow, but I've never heard the fact that the Assyrians destroyed the Israelites in the future as a possible motivator to not wanting Nineveh to be spared.

Comment: @Neil - I know. But the eagerness to prove your assumption may hinder your view from God's perspective. Point is, If Jonah knew Samaria was going to be taken by Assyria, he ran away just to save himself, not like a prophet did. Jonah prayed in 4:2 that "The Lord is a gracious and compassionate God, slow to anger and abounding in love, a God who relents from sending calamity." Perhaps this was the key message that Jonah/author wanted to bring to their Israel fellows, For the next prophet Amos was prophesying their destruction. If the Israelite repented, they would also be saved.

Answer (score 1):

> O Assyrian, the rod of mine anger, and the staff in their hand is mine indignation.
> — Isaiah 10:5

> We have given the hand to the Egyptians, and to the Assyrians, to be satisfied with bread.
> Our fathers have sinned, and are not; and we have borne their iniquities.
> — Lamentations 5:6–7

> Wherefore I have delivered her into the hand of her lovers, into the hand of the Assyrians, upon whom she doted.
> — Ezekiel 23:9

God may have used the Assyrians to punish his people on more than one occasion.

> **Second Assyrian Empire** …
> The Assyrian forces became a standing army, which, by successive improvements and careful discipline, was moulded into **an irresistible fighting machine**, and Assyrian policy was directed towards **the definite object of reducing the whole civilized world into a single empire** and thereby throwing its trade and wealth into Assyrian hands.
> — [Encyclopædia Britannica — Babylonia and Assyria](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Babylonia_and_Assyria#:%7E:text=reducing%20the%20whole,hands)

Legend says that the German city of Trier was founded by Assyrians:

> Trebeta was the legendary founder of Trier according to the Gesta Treverorum.
>
> According to a legend recorded in the 12th century, Deeds of the Treveri, **the city was founded by an mythological-unrecorded prince of Assyria named Trebeta**, placing the city's founding legend independent of and centuries before ancient Rome's.
>
> Trebeta's parents were said to have been Ninus, a legendary "**King of Assyria**" invented by the ancient Greeks (first mentioned by Ctesias), and an unknown mother who was Ninus's wife before Semiramis. Semiramis took control of the kingdom upon his father's death and Trebeta was forced into exile, wandering through Europe before settling at Trier.
> — [Trebeta - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebeta)

It's entirely possible that the German people are the descendants of the Assyrians.

See also:

- [The Babylonian Origins of Trier, p.591](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/10.1163/j.ctvbqs5nk.27.pdf?refreqid=fastly-default%3Aea9b8e1c8e56204fadf60a68ae0634f2&ab_segments=0%2FSYC-6646_phrase_search%2Fcontrol&origin=search-results)
- [Germany and the Holy Roman Empire, p.11](https://media.thetrumpet.com/Literature/EN/GER_EN_E01.pdf)

(I should also point out that the above claims are generally *not* accepted by mainstream historians.  But on the other hand, they generally tend to reject any history that relates directly to the Bible.)

Comment: This is very interesting. Are you saying that there really wasn't a single event, but more of a long-standing war that eventually led to captivity? And so the answer is probably partly?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that Jonah ("silly dove") hated and feared the Assyrians as a great and cruel power. Did he specifically see that their repentance would lead them to survive God's wrath and be used to defeat Israel and inflict cruelty and exile upon them? I think so. I see his story as an enacted prophecy, playing out the failing role of the Servant along with the Prodigal Son of Jesus's parable - running away from God and failing to lead other nations to God. When he does turn, as the Servant does, and preach to them he remains aloof and defiant, like the elder brother in the parable. At the end of the Jonah prophecy he sits under his vine (Israel) and sees it eaten by a worm and destroyed by the east wind (Assyria, then Babylon). His reluctant preaching and their salvation led to this fate. We see these images in the prophecies of his contemporary, Hosea.

Hosea 10:1 ESV

> Israel is a luxuriant vine that yields its fruit. The more his fruit increased, the more altars he built.

Hosea 13:15 ESV

> Though he may flourish among his brothers, the east wind, the wind of the Lord, shall come, rising from the wilderness,
> and his fountain shall dry up; his spring shall be parched, it shall strip his treasury of every precious thing.

The punishment coming to Israel via Assyria will be great:

Hosea 13:16 ESV

> Samaria shall bear her guilt, because she has rebelled against her God; they shall fall by the sword; their little ones shall be dashed in pieces, and their pregnant women ripped open.

These punishments due Israel for idolatry were foreseen by Moses:

Deuteronomy 28:39, 40, 45, 49 ESV

> <sup>**39**</sup> You shall plant vineyards and dress them, but you shall neither drink of the wine nor gather the grapes, for the worm shall eat them. <sup>**40**</sup> You shall have olive trees throughout all your territory, but you shall not anoint yourself with the oil, for your olives shall drop off. ... <sup>**45**</sup> “All these curses shall come upon you and pursue you and overtake you till you are destroyed, because you did not obey the voice of the Lord your God, to keep his commandments and his statutes that he commanded you. ... <sup>**49**</sup> The Lord will bring a nation against you from far away, from the end of the earth, swooping down like the eagle, a nation whose language you do not understand

And the same images were picked up by Ezekiel:

Ezekiel 19:10, 12 ESV

> <sup>**10**</sup> Your mother was like a vine in a vineyard ...
> <sup>**12**</sup> But the vine was plucked up in fury, cast down to the ground; the east wind dried up its fruit; they were stripped off and withered. As for its strong stem, fire consumed it.

Jonah's very name may indicate he is a stand-in for Israel in his book of prophecy:

Hosea 7:11 ESV

> Ephraim is like a dove, silly and without sense, calling to Egypt, going to Assyria. (“Like a dove” is the translation of “Jonah”.)

Ezekiel 7:16 ESV

> And if any survivors escape, they will be on the mountains, like doves of the valleys, all of them moaning, each one over his iniquity.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it said that God prophesied through Jonah the destruction of Israel through great success.
Can't find that anywhere in the Bible so I'm a bit suspicious, and wary.

But having said that, it makes sense that Jonah would not want to see Ninevah get spared from God's judgement because he knew Ninevah/ Assyria would destroy his Country.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/50596)

Comment: @ B. Davis - In Hermeneutics SE the questioner looks for direct answers, or definitive information to put him on the right path for resolution of the question. Admitting ignorance of  an answer does not further the conversation in a meaningful way.  Do more research to find answers, or remain silent if none are found.  Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!